# How to mask customized edit with regexp and maxlength of numbers only on Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for an any js-lib or custom solution to customize input field. Requirements:

1. Input can conain only numbers, whitespace, round brackets and dots.
2. Maxlength should be calculated and limited by length = 10 NUMBERS ONLY. So for another symbols no limit

Tried to use imask, jquery mask plugin and others but can't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve simple client side validation with HTML5 like this

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern="^[0-9().]{0,10}$" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

But there a many ways to solve it with jQuery. One example is [this validation plugin](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation).
Another [plugin could be this](https://github.com/victorjonsson/jQuery-Form-Validator).